# Problems with format of a list (list of lists?)

Tags: python, list, openpyxl

I am new to python and I have a list made from certain data from several xlsx files. I want to put all of the data into another xlsx file, but I am not able to work with the data in the list, because I do not understand the format of the list.

When I print the list (numbers) it looks like this:

```
[['A B 10', 2, 'A B 10', 3, 1, AC], ['A B 104', 3, 'A B 104', 2, -1, 'AC']]
[['D B 126', 3, 'D B 126', 2, -1, 'EFG 1'], ['D B 15', 3, 'D B 15', 2, -1, 'EFG 1']]
[]
[]
[['D B 544', 2, 'D B 544', 1, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 152', 3, 'D B 152', 2, -1, 'EFG 11'], ['D B 682', 3, 'D B 682', 2, -1, 'EFG 11']]
```

Whenever I am trying to put the list into an xlsx file, only the first sublist is added, like this:

[image: Worksheet]

I want it to be added like this:

[image: Desired worksheet]

The code I am using is this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os.chdir(r'C:\Myfolder')
files = glob.glob('*.xlsx') #Iterate through all xlsx files in desired folder
numbers = [] #Creating an open list
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file) #Creating dataframe of xlsx files with pandas
        m = (df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:, 1]) != 0 #Finding all of the rows where cell value number 4 - cell value number 1 is not equal to 0
        pos = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
        numbers = (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist()) #Adding these rows to the list
        print(numbers) #See numbers list written earlier

report = load_workbook(r"C:\Myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = report.create_sheet('Mysheet')
for _list in numbers:
    for row_data in _list:
        ws.append([row_data])
report.save(r"C:\Myworkbook.xlsx")
```

My questions are:
1: What sort of a list do I have? (The numbers list) It is not a list of lists as the list closes for every xlsx file that was iterated through. 
2: Does anyone know how I can put the data into my xlsx file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting a list of lists because you are overwriting the `numbers` variable for each pass in the loop.

Change

```
numbers = (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
```

to

```
numbers.append(df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
```